# Search Bar with Two options as dropdown (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, dropdown

Let's say I like to create a search bar (something similar to Github's search bar) as following specifications in ReactJS:

In an input when user start typing, 2 options as dropdown will appear. And when user click on the option will do something relevant to it.

I found "autocomplete" from Material-UI and tried different sites on Google but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for, those articles I found were all about dropdown menu with defined values.

Any idea or reference? Thank you very much!

[image: search bar sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 1 state to hold the input value. Then based on it to render the dropdown below. And you will need a submit handler with an optional search type param to reuse for onClick event of each Option inside the dropdown.

```
const [keyword, setKeyword] = React.useState('')

const handleSearch = (searchType) => {
  if (searchType) {
    // search with type (Author or Book)
    doSearch({ keyword, type })
  } else {
    // search with keyword only
    doSearch({ keyword })
  }
}
```

For render:

```
<input value={keyword} onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
<button onClick={() => handleSearch()}>Search</button>
// render the dropdown if value existed
{Boolean(keyword) && (
<div onClick={() => handleSearch('AUTHOR')}>{keyword} - Search in Author</div>
)}
```

Comment: Awesome brother! I will give an update on this issue later

Comment: I see in this case, I cannot navigate using up/down & enter key to select the option, any suggestion?

Comment: If you wanna support keyboard navigation, you will need to handle the key down event, then use a `switch(e.key)` to decide what're you want to do with it. Ex: ArrowDown/Up to focus next/previous option or Enter to submit search keyword with selected type.